# Can deduced return type for defaulted three-way comparison operator be concept-constrained in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, auto, c++-concepts, spaceship-operator

In the following program spaceship comparison operator with default implementation is declared with concept-constrained `auto` return type:

```
template<class T>
concept C = std::same_as<T, std::strong_ordering>;

struct A { 
    C auto operator <=>(const A &) const = default; 
};
```

This is accepted finely in GCC, however Clang complains:

```
error: deduced return type for defaulted three-way comparison operator must be 'auto', not 'C auto'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4PEYMax1q

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to constrain deduced return types at all, nevermind for `operator<=>`.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.spaceship#2.2 ?